# Joomla 3.0 article options not working

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to study Joomla 3.0 and right now, I have quite a number of articles on my page. I want to show the Author, Publish Date, etc but I can't seem to make them appear. I know how to change the parameters in the dashboard and I've already set everything to show the author and publish date from the menus to the modules. Why is it still not showing? Should there be something else I need to change?

Comment: The answer to this question can be found in details in this link(https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14075/jomla-3-4-article-option-not-working-for-individual-article)

Answer (score 3):

In joomla 3 the menu setting will be the one that "wins" if it varies from the general article settings in the dashboard config and in the individual article.

If all are set to show the chosen items, then I would check if the template in use have some content overrides that might exclude these. Try look in /yourtemplate/html/ and see if there are various override folders that might change the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer although, my problem is, I was given a template made from scratch to work with and there are no html folders on template. Another problem I'm having is trying to implement the "read more button" on the article. Even if I click on the said button, it doesn't show the rest of the text. Is there something I need to do for it?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the current release with how the parameter cascade is working.